# replacing set of PIPE charaters

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which is separated with 3 PIPES (|||). For e.g name|||url|||date|||amount|||

I am trying to do 2 things

1. extract specific column in another file say - amount to be separated in new file (it is 4th column in file)
2. replace all the 3 pipes with comma, so new files looks like - name,url,date,amount,

I want to replace comma with exactly 3 pipes as my data also has single pipe characters in between.

I have tried this - awk -F '[\|]'+ '{print $4}' temp.csv > temp1.csv. But this extracts if even single pipe is there in data.

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[|]{3}` as the field delimiter to extract a particular field from the original data:

```
$ awk -F '[|]{3}' '{ print $4 }' input.csv
```

To use a regular expression as the field separator requires GNU `awk`.

To replace all `|||` with a comma:

```
$ sed 's/|||/,/g' input.csv >output.csv
```

Comment: thanks "Kusalananda" for quick reply. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for extracting the fourth field of triple-pipe-delimited data:

```
sed 's/|||/,/g' /path/to/input | awk -F, '{print $4}'
```